# Feed read based on URL

Tags: feedparser

I have a different problem here. Have to develop a iphone app, in which it is going to show event updates from feeds.

If the feed list is too large(I mean the xml size) then it took very long time to return the result. Instead of that can i able to get only what i want.

Eg:
http://www.ted.com/talks/rss

This returns all top ted talks, but here can i read only one talk based on talk video id like this http://www.ted.com/talks/rss?~3/6dqCdBTpEn0/1019.